# Getting "NoneType object has no attribute" error trying to use turtle module

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

I am learning Python turtle. I copied this code from internet but I am getting this error `NoneType object has no attribute`.
I think error is in 2nd last line in `turtle.write()` function.

This is code:

```
import turtle
import random

# sets background
bg = turtle.Screen()
bg.bgcolor("black")

# Bottom Line 1
turtle.penup()
turtle.goto(-170,-180)
turtle.color("white")
turtle.pendown()
turtle.forward(350)

# Mid Line 2
turtle.penup()
turtle.goto(-160,-150)
turtle.color("white")
turtle.pendown()
turtle.forward(300)

# First Line 3
turtle.penup()
turtle.goto(-150,-120)
turtle.color("white")
turtle.pendown()
turtle.forward(250)

# Cake
turtle.penup()
turtle.goto(-100,-100)
turtle.color("white")
turtle.begin_fill()
turtle.pendown()
turtle.forward(140)
turtle.left(90)
turtle.forward(95)
turtle.left(90)
turtle.forward(140)
turtle.left(90)
turtle.forward(95)
turtle.end_fill()

# Candles
turtle.penup()
turtle.goto(-90,0)
turtle.color("red")
turtle.left(180)
turtle.pendown()
turtle.forward(20)

turtle.penup()
turtle.goto(-60,0)
turtle.color("blue")
turtle.pendown()
turtle.forward(20)

turtle.penup()
turtle.goto(-30,0)
turtle.color("yellow")
turtle.pendown()
turtle.forward(20)

turtle.penup()
turtle.goto(0,0)
turtle.color("green")
turtle.pendown()
turtle.forward(20)

turtle.penup()
turtle.goto(30,0)
turtle.color("purple")
turtle.pendown()
turtle.forward(20)

# Decoration
colors = ["red", "orange", "yellow", "green", "blue", "purple", "black"]
turtle.penup()
turtle.goto(-40,-50)
turtle.pendown()

for each_color in colors:
    angle = 360 / len(colors)
    turtle.color(each_color)
    turtle.circle(10)
    turtle.right(angle)
    turtle.forward(10)

# Happy Birthday message
turtle.penup()
turtle.goto(-150, 50)
turtle.color("pink")
turtle.pendown()
turtle.write("Happy Birthday PUNNU!", None, None, "24pt bold")
turtle.color("black")
```

Comment: See [Under what circumstances may I add "urgent" or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326569/under-what-circumstances-may-i-add-urgent-or-other-similar-phrases-to-my-quest)

Answer (score 1):

Here is the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/turtle.html#turtle.write) for `turtle.write()`.
You are supplying `NoneType` objects incorrectly. To set the font and leave the `move` and `align` parameters as their default values, change your second to last line to `turtle.write("Happy Birthday PUNNU!", font=("Arial", 24, "bold"))`

Comment: What should they do to fix it?

Comment: Change the second to last line to `turtle.write("Happy Birthday PUNNU!", font=("Arial", 24, "bold"))`

Comment: I think you should add that to your answer.